# Visualizing a 3D data set

Tags: matlab, plot, data-visualization

I've got a matrix of 200 by 50. I'd like to show a grid colored accordingly to the values with 50 on the y-axis and 200 on the x-axis. I tried to play with *mesh* but:

1. I get a lot of white space between the colored parts (I'd like the area to consist of a full fill of the squares, preferably with a frame around each too) and
2. the angle is 3D-ish, while I'd like it to be "straight from above".

Is *mesh* the correct tool for me or should I use something else?

This far, I've been using the following code. I'm open to comments and suggestions.

```
surf(values, 'EdgeColor','none');
view(90, 90);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [`surf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) instead, for example:

```
% Create a grid of x and y points
g= linspace(-2, 2, 20);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(g, g);

% Define the function Z = f(X,Y)
Z = 10*exp(-X.^2-Y.^2);

% "phong" and "gouraud" lighting are good for curved, interpolated surfaces. 
surf(X, Y, Z); 
view(30, 75);
colormap(jet(256));
shading interp;
light;
lighting phong;
```

[image]

Or if you really want a "view from above" use `view(0, 90);`

[image]

Comment: Ah - I was spot on with the *view* statement, then (although I need to enter 90-90 to get the same effect, because my scale is upside down). Now, what I'd like to get in there is a grid but the one I get to view has very strong edges. Ultimately, the grid's color would be a bit darker then the mid-value of adjacent tiles. Is that doable?

Comment: Yes it is, After the code I wrote above, use `hold on`, and add a grid using `mesh` and set it to be transparent, something like `h=mesh(X, Y, Z); alpha(h,0.1)`

Comment: Oooh, that's a good one. I'll give it a try as soon as I get to my MatLab computer. I won't have to place the mesh a few z-units above, will I? If so, can I do that by offsetting it or will I have to add a small fraction to each of the values used to create the mesh?

Comment: I've just placed it on the same coordinates. Tweak the transparency using the alpha value, and whatever handles of the mesh plot you want to get the effect needed...